# Get highest Value from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the highest value from a column of a MySQL Table:

example:

```
Code (PK)   | ...
AT10000
DE10001
FR10002
```

How I can get the Value "10002"?

Comment: Do you wanna get the highest integer value of the Code column? Or do you wanna consider the char values?

Comment: I want to get the highest integer value of the column

Comment: Someone answered. But that's it. Just use substr function with the max value. Do not use the solution with order by and position of the record. That's not a good pratice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select max(substring(code, 3) + 1)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the entire row corresponding to the max value, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM yourTable T
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(T.code, 3) DESC
```

Or you also can use this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable T
WHERE SUBSTRING(T.code, 3) = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(T2.code, 3)
                              FROM yourTable T2)
```

And this last one if you just want to have the max value without info about the row:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(T.code, 3) AS [value]
FROM yourTable T
```

Hope this will help you.